# How to get redirect function's output in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get "**authorization_code**" from a provider (OAuth2 related task).

I wrote a basic function in my views.py;

```
# This is not the best function, I know.
def auth_for_app(request):    
    return redirect ('https://www.PROVIDER-WEBSITE.com/admin/user/auth?client_id=xxxx&response_type=code&state=1234567890&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/auth')
```

I am getting the result on my console (terminal). I can see the **authorization_code** which I need for the further processes. How can I get it as a value in my code?

**EDIT (added products/urls.py):**

products/urls.py;

```
*** some imports here ***

app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='base'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('auth/', views.auth_for_app, name='auth_for_app'),
]
```

Comment: Do you have a url `/products/auth`? If not I guess you will need one in order to receive feedback - but I can't remember the last time I have implemented an OAuth workflow by hand. There are plenty of-the-shelf packages for this in Python/Django.

Comment: Yes, I have a url like that. I am adding it to my question now. It has been 2 days and still I cannot figure it out!

Comment: Just a wild guess because I don't know what provider you are using but perhaps `redirect_uri` must be different from the URL you use to start the OAuth flow - lets say `products/oauth_callback/`. Then check `request.GET` at your `oauth_callback` view. Something like `def oauth_callback(request): request.session['authorization_code'] = request.GET.get('authorization_code')` and then redirect the user to the index page.